# Using GOTO in C# Console Application. Change my mind that it's a bad idea

Tags: c#, console

So I was talking with my coworkers and they said that `GOTO` statement is a bad idea no matter what!

I'm just trying to figure out what does the community think.

Here's my example:
I created a small console application that has two functions

> What would you like to do?
>
> 1. Parse a file
> 2. Exit

My code looks something like this pseudo code below:

```
Start:
Console.Write("What would you like to do?");
Console.Write("1. Parse a file");
Console.Write("2. Exit");

var key = Console.ReadKey();

if (key == "1")
 GOTO ParseFile;
If (key == "2")
 return null;

ParseFile:
Console.Write("File location");
var fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
var parsed = parser.Parse(fileLocation);
...do work on parsed..
GOTO Start:
```

My idea is to give the user (me) the ability not to have to start the application every time I parse a file, but if I have more than one file to parse I can just go back to starting over.

Comment: A simple `if` condition would suffice just fine inside a method that *you* could call again...

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea no matter what

Comment: Download a medium-sized open source C# app and set about converting all the method calls to `goto`s then; you'll soon change your mind that it's the future

Answer (score 2):

GOTO adds unnecessary complexity and if the code is more complicated it can be hard to track and fix. Most of the things that GOTOs do can be accomplished with already existent control structures with break statements.

You can extract methods from your code and make it more modular and easy to modify instead of having it all in one listing with GOTO statements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not here, in this case using if, switch or goto would suffice, but imagine a code that has not 1 or 2 conditions but 10 lets say, and you have to find where that goto label is. This is just the tip of the iceberg of the problems a goto will cause.

When you use goto you are getting rid of the stack trace so when it executes it goes to that point and continue execution from that point on... so it can lead to disasters

Answer (score 2):

GOTO breaks encapsulation and is a sign of lazy programming.  It is infinitely easier to do bad things with GOTO than it is with proper coding techniques.

Your example will parse a file if someone writes anything besides 2, which may not be apparent by looking at the code, because it falls through after the second if statement.

If you instead methodized your ParseFile section, you would know explicitly when it was to be called, instead of accidentally falling through to it.

Flow of control should be intentional, because bugs are already far too prevalent without adding more due to laziness.

Answer (score 1):

there is no reason at all to use goto in your console application.
the first GOTO ParseFile is just a break in a switch case (a switch case would be much more readable since you can get multiple break condition and know they are all in the same if clause), the GOTO Start is just a simple while in the beginning of your application (again a while would be much more readable, since you will be able to tell in one second what block of code will repeat itself, also you will be able to know why it should be repeated (with goto you will not be able to tell why repeat that code block until you read every line of it and know when you will not reach that goto)).

the main reason why not to use goto is "conditional jump". If you don't know why you should jump in your code your code will be hard to read after a while.

Also, your code will be even easier.

```
print instruction
if(key != 1)
  return null;

while(key == 1){
  (do not print instruction first time)
  parse...
}

return null;
```

much much easier than your strange code.
You just ask the user to start (and return if not), and you continue to parse if the user want to continue, when not return.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you should use `switch` or `if`, however if you think you will have to extend functionality of your app in the future you should consider strategy pattern. It enables us extend functionality of the application with changing code and it's a perfect example of respecting open-closed principle (O in SOLID).

Whenever you see a switch or if statements think about how easy or hard is to add another case. In the sample from your question if you have to add another command to your application strategy would work like this.

First we define an interface that can handle commands:

```
interface ICommandHandler
{
    bool SupportsCommand(string command);
    void ExecuteCommand(string command);
    IEnumerable<string> GetSupportedCommands();
}
```

Interface has couple of methods. `SupportsCommand` returns true if command is supported by the concrete implementation of the interface. `ExecuteCommand` executes the command (it can return `Task` if `void` isn't good enough for your use case). `GetSupportedCommands` is there just for printing out what commands are supported by the application.

Next we implement it by a couple of handlers:

```
class ParseFileCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSupportedCommands()
    {
        yield return "parse";
    }

    public bool SupportsCommand(string command)
    {
        return command == "parse";
    }
}

class PrintFileCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSupportedCommands()
    {
        yield return "print";
    }

    public bool SupportsCommand(string command)
    {
        return command == "print";
    }
}
```

Next step is to define class that can work as proxy for calling specific `ICommandHandler` implementation:

```
class CommandStrategies
{
    private List<ICommandHandler> _commandHandlers;

    public CommandStrategies()
    {
        _commandHandlers = typeof(CommandStrategies)
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && typeof(ICommandHandler).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
            .Cast<ICommandHandler>()
            .ToList();
    }

    public bool SupportsCommand(string command)
    {
        return _commandHandlers.Any(x => x.SupportsCommand(command));
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        var handler = _commandHandlers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupportsCommand(command));
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSupportedCommands()
    {
        return _commandHandlers
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetSupportedCommands())
            .Distinct();
    }
}
```

In constructor we find and instantiate all implementations of the interface using reflection. This can only work if none of the implementations have constructor with parameter(s) and if all implementations are in same assembly (if that is not the case, instances of the handlers could be passed to the constructor of `CommandStrategies`. Methods are just proxy-ing calls to implementations of `ICommandHandler`.

Only thing left is to implement infrastructure (`Console`) code, we can do that in entry class of the application.

```
class Program
{
    static CommandStrategies CommandHandlers = new CommandStrategies();

    static void Main()
    {
        PrintSupportedCommands();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter command:");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            if (command == "exit") return;

            bool isCommandSupported = CommandHandlers.SupportsCommand(command);
            if (!isCommandSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Command is not supported.");
                PrintSupportedCommands();
            }
            else
            {
                CommandHandlers.ExecuteCommand(command);
            }
        }
    }

    static void PrintSupportedCommands()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Supported commands are:");
        foreach (var cmd in CommandHandlers.GetSupportedCommands())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cmd);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("exit");
    }
}
```

No if you need to support another command handler, you can just add another class that imeplements `ICommandHandler` and everything else will work as before, no need to add another `case` for `switch` or another `if else`.

This solution might be an overkill but for critical parts of the application is often worth it.

Comment: Yea that was a very thorough answer. I have used the strategy pattern in a more complex app where I know that I was going to have an N number of objects, actually I use the strategy pattern almost daily.  But this answer is great :)  While it is a bit overkill for my two commands that I will only use once, if I was writing a bigger application I would use that method.

Answer (score 0):

You guys have changed my mind!
Thanks for the thoughtful feedback. It was much better than just reading or hearing "DON'T DO IT!".